# virtual desktop and multiple monitors

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

I have the following setup:

- one thinkpad with windows 10 on it,
- dock with 2 additional monitor connected to it

What I want to achieve:
When I am connected to the dock I have 3 screens with one desktop, and when I am disconnection from the dock I want 3 virtual desktop with the content of the screens.

Is it possible, how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 does not have this capability natively. A google search appears to find a few third-party applications that accomplish this. I have not used any of the applications suggested though and cannot advise on their capability:

https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+10+convert+physical+screens+to+virtual+desktops&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8